# Java writing two buffered streams to response OutputStream

Tags: java, jasper-reports, outputstream, fileoutputstream

Currently am working in exporting the Huge data to Excel file using Jasper Reports. Am trying to split the dataset into chunks and creating jasper print object and exporting to multiple Excel files.

After that am reading the file using FileInput, BufferdInputStream and copying to `response.getOutputstream`. Like that I need to read from each file and should copy to `response.getOutputstream`.

But at the end, when exported file is corrupted, and data is not readable and don't know what format it is.

Any workable solution to export huge data using Jasper Reports is also appreciated.

```
while ((readBytes = buf1.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                servletOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                servletOutputStream.flush();
            }
```

Above code am repeating in loop to read the data from each file by replacing 
buf1 with new data.

Comment: Are you writing both streams to the same OutputStream?

Comment: You don't need to `.flush()` on each write, just flush after the `while` loop.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't with your splitting? Have you tried to reconstruct the file from all its inputs and seen whether it was still valid?

Comment: Are you doing `buf1.close()` and `buf1 = new ...InputStream...` inside the loop?

Comment: Yes am sure while splitting the data there is no problem. And yes am doing buf1.close() and buf1 = new InputStream inside the Loop... But still am getting the same Unformated content in excel.